# Pourquoi « dictée » se terminant par « ée » ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, noms, suffixes

En orthographe, il y a une règle qui stipule que tous les noms féminins se terminant par *-té* ne prennent pas de *-e* final.

Exemples :

- « beauté » et non « beautée »
- « sévérité » et non « sévéritée »

Cependant, cette règle ne s'applique pas pour certains noms féminins comme « dictée » (ou « montée », « butée », « jetée », « portée », « pâtée », « pelletée »...) qui prend un *-e* final.

Savez-vous pourquoi ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Le beau engendre la *beauté*,
- le sévère engendre la *sévérité*.

Beauté et sévérité sont des noms féminins dérivés de noms masculins.

La *dictée* n'a pas pour source un nom, mais un verbe au participe passé, et comme c'est un nom féminin, l'accord se fait.

[L'académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/dict%C3%A9e) féminise ce nom en l'identifiant à une *action (de dicter)*, en spécifiant cette dernière par *dictée*.

*Sous la dictée de,* s'entend alors : *sous (ou par) l'actions des choses dites*

Comment: @cl-r: pour avoir des liens qui marchent il faut passer par l'interface du [cnrtl.fr](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/).

Answer (score 5):

Je crois que la finale "ée" est l'option par défaut au féminin. Elle s'applique notamment (mais pas exclusivement) à des contenus, des résultats ou tout simplement à des dérivés morphologiques directs (assiette/assiettée, soir/soirée, lancer/lancée). Rien n'explique des mots comme idée ou bouée, si ce n'est que "ée" est la finale par défaut au féminin.

La finale "é" pour des noms féminins (qui n'est donc pas la règle, mais plutôt l'exception), s'applique à des concepts, des notions, des termes génériques (bonté, santé, méchanceté, amitié, finalité...). À noter que l'équivalent de cette finale en anglais est "y" (charity, beauty). Seul incohérence dans ces explications: le mot "clé", désolée! :-)

Comment: *Clé* est l’orthographe moderne du mot *clef*, on emploie indifféremment les deux sauf pour *clef de voûte*, à cause de *clef* référençant ici une "pierre en forme de coin placée au centre de la voûte", synonyme de *claveau*.

Comment: Les 1352 noms communs en é sont à 60% féminins contre 40% masculins. Les 474 noms communs en ée sont à 94% féminins. Exceptions notables :  apogée, caducée, lycée, mausolée, musée, périgée, périnée, scarabée, trophée.

Answer (score 4):

*Dictée* est construit sur un participe passé, c'est un raccourci pour quelque chose qui devait originellement ressembler à *Ecriture dictée* ou *Epreuve dictée*. Il me semble que c'est un vestige de cette forme qui subsiste dans le "e" final.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse, pourrais-tu partager une source sûre qui confirme tes propos ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas criant, mais c'est évoqué à la toute fin de [l'article du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dict%C3%A9e).

Answer (score 1):

Le suffixe **-té**, qui sert à former des noms abstraits surtout dérivés d'adjectifs et qu'on retrouve dans « clarté, fierté, bonté, volonté, liberté, nécessité... », vient du suffixe latin -tas, accusatif -tatem, du même sens, et s'écrit tout naturellement sans e muet.

Dans le mot « dictée », dérivé du verbe « dicter », on a plutôt affaire au suffixe **-ée** qui sert à former des noms d'action (cf. « huée, fessée, raclée, curée, veillée... »). Ces dérivés sont en fait identiques à la forme du participe passé féminin, cf. « prise, crainte, crue, bouillie, saillie... », et comporte naturellement un e muet.